# gitlab CI cannot clone repository after upgrade to 8.0

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I recentrly upgraded my gitlab server to 8.0, migrated my CI data using the [CI migration guide](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/migrate_ci_to_ce/README.html), and push some commits, but now all my builds failed because it cannot fetch data.

docker runner states :

```
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/ns/project'...
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab-ci-token:d33[...]a6@git.geekwu.org/ns/project.git/'

ERROR: Build failed with: exit code 128
```

I've tried to re-register runners but got no more success

I've tried to change the CI token (this token is project-specific) without success

NB: the projects are private, but was built with gitlab 7.x

Comment: What happens if you try to run the same command manually?

Comment: I get the same error message

Comment: You could try to regenerate the token associated to Gitlab CI from Gitlab then (The applications settings). As the Gitlab CI was likely to change, maybe the token have been invalidated somehow?

Comment: I've tried to change the CI token (this token is project-specific) without success

Comment: Ok. Feel free to report an issue on the Gitlab repo. They maybe be able to help you better there: https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/issues or the Github mirror: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues

Comment: I've done that. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2658

Comment: Curious to know what it is. I haven't started the upgrade yet :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service tokens was out of sync with project tokens.

To correct them, one can connect to database, get tokens in service table, with type 'GitlabCiService' : token is encoded in JSON in the field properties

Put it into CI token (in web application, it's in CI > project > settings > CI token ; in the database it's in the token field of ci_projects table)

**EDIT** [Bug report is closed](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2658#note_2243686), marked as fixed